# How I can refer multiple equation in Latex?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

Suppose, I want to refer multiple equations (1), (2), (3), (4), (5) and (7)
so that they appear as (1-5, 7):

```
\documentclass[fleqn,preprint,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{1}\psi([e_1,e_2]) = \psi(e_2) = e_2 = (e_2,2e_3) = (-2e_3,e_2) = (\psi(e_1), \psi(e_2))\\
\label{2}\psi([e_1,e_3]) = \psi(2e_3) = 2e_1 = (e_1,2e_3) = (-2e_3,e_1) = (\psi(e_1),\psi(e_3))\\
\label{3}\psi([e_2,e_3]) = 0 = (e_2,e_1) = (\psi(e_2),\psi(e_3)),\\
\label{4}\left\{e_4, e_1\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_2\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_3\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_1+\epsilon\,e_2\right\},\\
\label{5}\left\{e_1, e_2\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_3, e_1\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_3, e_2\right\},\\
\label{6}\left\{e_4, e_1\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_2\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_3\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_1+\epsilon\,e_2\right\},\\
\label{7}\text{Nor}_{L_4\oplus L_3}\left(\{e_2\}\right)/\{e_2\}=\,\{e_1, e_3, e_4\}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The simple way is to write `(\ref{1}-\ref{5},\ref{6})` ...

Comment: Using numbers as labels is not really wise

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Why it is so ? What should we use then ?

Comment: @IgotiT: Use meaningful names, not numbers. It's hard to remember the number!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I use Sumatra pdf, double clicking on pdf takes me to exact position of equation in compiler, so remembering equation label is not a problem for me.

Comment: @IgotiT: That's not the point.

Comment: @IgotiT The whole point of using names is for ease of future editing. Any numbering should be automated. Say you have `\label{1}`, `\label{2}`, `\label{3}` in that order, and now you want to add a new equation between `\label{1}` and `\label{2}`. Are you going to renumber everything?

Comment: @lastresort: I can still add label and I do that very often, suppose I have total 100 labels from 1 to 100 and if I want insert new equation between equation 34 and 36 then I would assign label 101  to this equation and compiler also tell me every time that which labels are already in use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\cref` command (or its capitalised version `\Cref`) from `cleveref` sorts and compresses by default lists of references. You can make groups inserting between them a pair of commas. Furthermore, it adds the word `e/Equation(s)` according to the context, and uses by default the abbreviated forms `e/Eq(s)`. If uses the active language of the document, and terms can be easily customised through a `cleveref.cfg` file. Last comment: if you use `hyperref`, it has to be loaded *after* it.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,preprint,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\newcommand\crefrangeconjunction{\textendash}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{1}\psi([e_1,e_2]) = \psi(e_2) = e_2 = (e_2,2e_3) = (-2e_3,e_2) = (\psi(e_1), \psi(e_2))\\
\label{2}\psi([e_1,e_3]) = \psi(2e_3) = 2e_1 = (e_1,2e_3) = (-2e_3,e_1) = (\psi(e_1),\psi(e_3))\\
\label{3}\psi([e_2,e_3]) = 0 = (e_2,e_1) = (\psi(e_2),\psi(e_3)),\\
\label{4}\left\{e_4, e_1\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_2\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_3\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_1+\epsilon\,e_2\right\},\\
\label{5}\left\{e_1, e_2\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_3, e_1\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_3, e_2\right\},\\
\label{6}\left\{e_4, e_1\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_2\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_3\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_1+\epsilon\,e_2\right\},\\
\label{7}\text{Nor}_{L_4\oplus L_3}\left(\{e_2\}\right)/\{e_2\}=\,\{e_1, e_3, e_4\}
\end{align}

We see from  \cref{1,4,3,2,5,,7} …

\Cref{1,2,3,,6} show that …


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One example: Use `\crefrange` or `\Crefrange` or the `\cref` or `\Cref` commands which understands CSV lists of references.

Be sure to omit white space characters in the CSV - list of `\cref` etc.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,preprint,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\psi([e_1,e_2]) = \psi(e_2) = e_2 = (e_2,2e_3) = (-2e_3,e_2) = (\psi(e_1), \psi(e_2)) \label{eq:some} \\
\psi([e_1,e_3]) = \psi(2e_3) = 2e_1 = (e_1,2e_3) = (-2e_3,e_1) = (\psi(e_1),\psi(e_3)) \label{eq:foo}\\
\psi([e_2,e_3]) = 0 = (e_2,e_1) = (\psi(e_2),\psi(e_3)),\label{eq:foobar}\\
\left\{e_4, e_1\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_2\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_3\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_1+\epsilon\,e_2\right\},\label{eq:foobarfoo}\\
\left\{e_1, e_2\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_3, e_1\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_3, e_2\right\},\label{eq:foobarfoobar}\\
\left\{e_4, e_1\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_2\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_3\right\},\,\,\,\left\{e_4, e_1+\epsilon\,e_2\right\}\label{eq:foobarother}\\
\text{Nor}_{L_4\oplus L_3}\left(\{e_2\}\right)/\{e_2\}=\,\{e_1, e_3, e_4\}\label{eq:foobarnew}
\end{align}

\Crefrange{eq:some}{eq:foobarfoobar}
or \cref{eq:some,,eq:foobar,eq:foobarfoo,eq:foobarfoobar,eq:foobarnew}% eq:otherfoobar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't fix the math style, since the question was about referencing