# Combining different LaTeX articles / documents: How to avoid mixing of equation labels between different chapters of thesis?

Tags: cross-referencing

I am going to write my PhD thesis. I have 7 to 8 papers written in latex. Now I want to compile all the papers in to chapters of thesis. Since all the paper have almost common equation labels so when I compile my latex file then wrong equations get referred from same label in other chapters. Is possible to avoid mixing of equation within different chapters of thesis, so that I can refer an equation independent within same chapter without bothering the similar equation labels in other  chapters? Or I need to compile chapter differently into single file by using command `\include{chapterX}` ?

Here is example code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,preprint,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{\Large This is my thesis}
\end{center}
\vskip 5pt
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{}
\section{This is my Introduction}
Here is my equation
\begin{align}
\label{1}x^2+y^2=1
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\label{2}x^2+y^2=1
\end{align}
I can refer this equation as \eqref{1}. But since chapter 1 and 2 have common labels so the wrong equation get referred. 
\chapter{}
\section{This is second Chapter}
Here is my another equation in second chapter 
\begin{align}
\label{1}\tan(x)=x
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\label{2}\cot(x)=x
\end{align}
I can also refer this equation as \eqref{1}. How I can refer equation in a chapter without mixing labels from other chapters ?
\section*{References}
\bibliography{My.Bibtex.Library}
   \bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not so experienced, but I think the problem you have is due to same equations labels in different chapters. IMO the only option you have is to give labels some unique value, e.g. "ch1:eq1" for 1st equation in chapter 1 and "ch2:eq1" for 1st equation in chapter 2.

Comment: Labelling with `\label{1}` and `\label{2}` is apparently not the best way of using labels. Repeating the label with the same label identifier is an error and you should have noticed the warning messages about `multiply defined labels`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I have found solution my problem, see answer to my own question. Now next problem is, how I can refer equation from chapter 2 in chapter 3 when I have similar labels in both chapters. The both chapters are saved in different `Tex` files by different names.

Comment: @IgotiT: No, that's not the solution actually. Again: Don't repeat label names!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: What should I do now!!! I completely messed my latex source code with similar label. Is there any solution or I have to change labels or should take output for each chapter as pdf and then combine pdf?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: You have cautioned me of using numbered label on Jun 2016 but at that time I could not realized the importance: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314217/how-i-can-refer-multiple-equation-in-latex

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I am changing my labels by putting text along with labels. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Just open every article (LaTeX document) separately and **search and replace** `\label{` with `\label{Paper01_` and so on.
- **search and replace** should be possible with most decent text or LaTeX editors.
- Do the same for `\eqref{` and `\ref{`.
- Do it for every article, `Paper01` to `Paper_07`.
- **Then you can combine the LaTeX codes of the different articles and the labels are unique!**

And, of course, do all that with a **copy of your project files** in case something goes wrong.

Comment: I had to do the same as you suggested. Thanks.